# Is "gesunden" in "ein wenig gesunden Menschenverstand" starke or gemischte Flexion?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending

> ein wenig **gesunden** Menschenverstand

Should I consider this *gesunden* to be starke Flexion (ohne Artikel), or gemischte Flexion (mit *ein)?*

In other words, should I consider *ein wenig* as an adverb and use starke Flexion, or does *ein* lead me to use gemischte Flexion?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use strong inflection, as you can see for example in *mit ein wenig gesunde**m** Menschenverstand*.

The reason is that non-inflectable phrases like *ein paar*, *ein bisschen* etc. require the following adjective to use strong inflection (see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives#Strong_inflection)), and *ein wenig* is among those.